# Parenthesization Matrix Chain Multiplication

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to test some parenthesizations for matrix chain multiplication. could anyone can share a free webs source where could i get parenthesization for my data. or any free available code for this in any language. So, that i may use the code to test parenthesization and could compare it with my newly developed technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a code thanks all. If anyone else wants that is available at `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).